# I need to implement the function which accepts color as a string parameter and return it as a json_encode

Tags: php, json

I want to get the function that can accept a string parameter and return it to json format.
for example if i call $ballcolor->getBall("orange");
then the output// should be:
{ "color":"orange", "ball": ["basketball"]}

and if a call does not have any color for that ball:
{ "color":"black", "ball": []}

```
class BallColor
    {
      private $ballcolor;

      function BallColor($ballcolor)
      {
        $this->ballcolor = $ballcolor;
      }

      public function getBall($color)
      {

        return NULL;

      }
    }

    $ballcolor = new BallColor(array(
        "orange" => array("basketball"),
        "white" => array("football")
    ));

    echo $ballcolor->getBall("orange");
    echo "\n";
    echo $ballcolor->getBall("black");
```

Comment: Is there anything you have tried? What problems do you face?

Comment: Of course I only got blank page if I return NULL but if I try to change the NULL with the $color parameter I'm getting the parameter that I set in the function and I don't know what else to do with my code to get the result that I want.

Comment: well: get the desired value out of `$this->ballcolor`, then build the object you need to return, then json_encode that.

Comment: `return json_encode(Array("color" => $color, "ball" => $this->ballcolor[$color]));`

Comment: I'm getting the color but the ball is null.

Comment: because of the falsy constructor! Sorry, I made a typo before: it should be `__construct`, not `__constructor`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the desired value out of `$this->ballcolor` after checking it's there, then build the array you need to return, then json_encode that:

```
class BallColor
{
      private $ballcolor;

      function __construct($ballcolor)
      {
        $this->ballcolor = $ballcolor;
      }

      public function getBall($color)
      {
          // condensed into oneliners:
          if(isset($this->ballcolor[$color])) {
              return json_encode(Array("color" => $color, "ball" => $this->ballcolor[$color]));
          } else {
              return json_encode(Array("color" => "black", "ball" => []));
          }
      }
}

$ballcolor = new BallColor(array(
    "orange" => array("basketball"),
    "white" => array("football")
));

echo $ballcolor->getBall("orange");
echo "\n";
echo $ballcolor->getBall("black");
```

Output:

```
{"color":"orange","ball":["basketball"]} 
{"color":"black","ball":[]}
```

Comment: It works :) and thank you for the clarification of the __construct I also forgot to change it, oh and I saw one mistake I need to clarify when you return json_encode(Array("color" => "black", "ball" => [])); I need to change the "color" => "black" to "color" => $color to edit the color anytime I want but thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
function __construct($ballcolor)
```

instead of

```
function BallColor($ballcolor)
```

as you constructor, unless your php version is old.